# Transitioning div is shown above another div when it should always be below (on Safari)

Tags: html, css, safari, css-position, css-transitions

I have a flip card with a transition `transform: rotateY( 180deg );`, in the lower right of this card there's a div with an icon inside.
This icon should always be above the card but on Safari, during the transition it appears to be below the card div. When the transition ends, it goes back on top. I tried using z-index with no changes.

CSS:

```
.neutral-unit-box {
  background-color: #000;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 270px 570px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 24px 24px 24px 24px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow:
  0px 0px 2px #000,
  0px 0px 2px #000,
  0px 0px 2px #000,
  0px 0px 2px #000;
  width: 300px;
}

.loyalty-card-content {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.loyalty-card.flipped .loyalty-card-content {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.neutral-unit-box, .neutral-unit-box-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; /* Chrome */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Chrome */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Chrome */
}

.neutral-unit-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.flip-card-icon {
  background-image: url(/img/neutrals/flip-card-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="loyalty-card-<%= _.kebabCase(key) %>" class="loyalty-card" onclick="flip('<%= _.kebabCase(key) %>');">
                <div class="loyalty-card-content">
                  <div class="unit-box mx-auto pt-4 background-<%= type %>">
                    <div class="neutral-unit-name text-center">
                      <h1><%= key %><% if ('tot' in unit[key]){ %><sup>(<%= unit[key].tot %>)</sup><% } else { %><% } %></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="neutral-unit-sil mx-auto" style="background-image: url(/img/bg.png)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="loyalty-card-body <% if (!("requirement" in unit[key])) { %>no-spellbook<% } %> <%= type %>">

                      <p class="text-center"><span class="combat-color">Combat: <%- unit[key].combat %></span></p>
                      <% } %>
                      <div clas='ability'>
                        <p><%- unit[key].ability %></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="neutral-unit-box unit-box-back background-<%= type %>">
                    <p> ok </p>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class='flip-card-icon'></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I think this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925174/css-after-rotatey180deg-z-index-not-working-as-intended

Comment: Not sure with this particular application but, `z-index` typically wants a `position` value in your css before it will show. I would just make sure your icon and your card both have `position` and `z-index` applied and try that.

Comment: @CalvinBonner I tried position + zindex, and even transformZ